# Bad Practice to Pass ByRef and ByVal Parameters In Same Routine?

Tags: vb.net, language-agnostic, programming-languages

Is it considered bad practice (VB.NET or any language) to code a function with both ByVal and ByRef parameters as used in my getFile function below?

```
Function getFile(ByVal channel As Integer, _
                 ByRef Filename As String, _
                 ByRef Filesize As String) As Integer
...
End Function

...
Dim status As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim filesize As Integer

For channel In 1 To 16
   status = getFile(channel, filename, filesize) 
   ...
Next channel
```

Comment: I can see where this mechanism can be useful, but ultimately, the method's output becomes cluttered:

It returns an integer and (sometimes) a filename/filesize.  I would have it return a simple struct with the three types of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually try to avoid `ByRef` all together, it often ends up being ugly and confusing.
The fact that you're mixing `ByVal` and `ByRef` doesn't affect readibility any more than just having all `ByRef` IMHO.

For example, if I only need the filename, I'd still need to pass in a filesize variable, which I think makes it a bit uglier. And when reading code it can be easy to miss that a parameter might be changed.

As Assaf also says in his comment, instead I'd normally try to get around the whole issue by having the method return some kind of structure that can contain all the return data. and if it failed I'd throw an exception rather than return the status (assuming that the status is some kind of error).

Comment: Agreed. use byref and byval as necessary and appropriate and you'll be gold. Most parameters are one way, passed in, so they SHOULD be byval. but in some circumstances you need to be able to modify a passed in parameter. Not super common, but that's why you have Byref.

Comment: I should add, though that if a function needs to return a value, it's usually best to make that the function return value and not a byref param.

Comment: and if a function needs to return more than one value, you should probably create a class or struct specifically for that purpose.